How to find which resource an IP belong to in K8s
I have a microk8s cluster with MetalLb enabled, giving an IP to a NginX service (LoadBalancer) with NginX Ingress
I have successfully exposed my other services through NginX but from the log, it seems that traffic is coming from an internal IP "10.1.240.128"
I would like to first see how the traffic is routed internally, and secondly, find a way to forward the real client ip to NginX to apply proper filtering
However, I can't find any resource that hold this IP. What can I do?
microk8s kubectl get endpoints --all-namespaces -o wide | grep 10.1.240.128
microk8s kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide | grep 10.1.240.128
microk8s kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide | grep 10.1.240.128
microk8s kubectl get nodes -o wide | grep 10.1.240.128
all return nothing
The NginX log
10.1.240.128 - - [02/Dec/2024:16:03:57 +0000] "GET /api/v1/login/status HTTP/2.0" 200 124 "https://my-domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0" 3401 0.001 [kube-system-kubernetes-dashboard-443] [] 10.1.44.175:8443 124 0.001 200 ca7a57e83bea55234652d92fe5c37c0b
10.1.240.128 - - [02/Dec/2024:16:03:57 +0000] "GET /api/v1/csrftoken/token HTTP/2.0" 200 85 "https://my-domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0" 3392 0.001 [kube-system-kubernetes-dashboard-443] [] 10.1.44.175:8443 85 0.000 200 7b74844d5784b4cdfd6b3e69bb753f5f
10.1.240.128 - - [02/Dec/2024:16:03:57 +0000] "POST /api/v1/token/refresh HTTP/2.0" 200 1493 "https://my-domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0" 5236 0.007 [kube-system-kubernetes-dashboard-443] [] 10.1.44.175:8443 1493 0.007 200 adaca01bfced622d953c291820d02023


Have you tried checking if the IP address is associated with the system where you deployed microk8s by issuing ip addr ?

No. The physical system where I deployed microk8s is on 192.168.1.x
